# why qr icon is not showing in gmail sending options list ? QR QR scanner QR Code

Tags: qr-code

why qr icon is not showing in gmail sending options list ?  QR QR scanner QR Code

why qr icon is not showing in gmail sending options list ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IanBD.png)

**formatting options**

attach files

insert link

insert emoji

insert file using drive

insert photo

toggle confidential mode

insert signature

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.